# Why SequenceType.dropFirst(_:) return Self.SubSequence instead of Self?

Tags: swift

Trying to understand [`SequenceType` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FPs12SequenceType9dropFirstFSiwx11SubSequence):

```
protocol SequenceType {
    associatedtype SubSequence
    @warn_unused_result func dropFirst(_ n: Int) -> Self.SubSequence
    /* ... */
}
```

Why we ever need `associatedtype SubSequence`, why not `Self`, `SequenceType`?

Comment: For example, `someArray.dropFirst()` returns an `ArraySlice`, not an `Array`.

Comment: @MartinR thank you, now I got this connection in my mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done for increased flexibility. Allowing a class conforming to `SequenceType` protocol to define a *different* class to represent its subsequence lets implementers construct lightweight classes that present a view into original sequence without making a copy, while preserving the ability to reuse the same sequence type as `Subsequence`.

Consider an implementation of a tree set collection that keeps its elements sorted. An implementation of `dropFirst` has an option of returning a "subtree" collection that is linked to the original tree, but has a different starting node. An implementation of such subtree could be extremely lightweight - you would need the same amount of space regardless of the size of the tree, an O(1). In contrast, binding implementers to the same tree class would force them to make a copy of the subtree, which is O(n).

Comment: And in some cases those O(n) implementations may not even be possible. Consider the case where the `Sequence` includes metadata. For example, I might create a `Filehandle` sequence that includes things like the name of the file that was opened and the date when it was opened. It may not be possible to generate another `Filehandle` that is a subsequence of the fist one (and it definitely would not be possible to do in a generic way).